# Jenkins pipeline using anyof

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

how can i use 2 anyof. What i want is both condition must be met then only execute the job

```
stage("Spring App") {
  when {
    anyOf {
      environment name: 'key1', value: 'true'
      environment name: 'key2', value: 'true'
    }
    anyOf {
      environment name: 'key3', value: 'string1'
      environment name: 'key4', value: 'string2'
      environment name: 'key5', value: 'string3'
    }
  }
```

I need met both condition . How to use and between 2 anyof

Comment: Take a look at the `allOf` condition in the `when` step [Documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when), it should help you achieve what you want.

Comment: Hi so this is the correct approach right. we need use allof. As i saw mine s working but not sure whether it is correct approach

Comment: It is the correct approach (and probably the only built in one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap everything into the allOf condition, like this :

```
allOf {
    anyOf {
        environment name: 'key1', value: 'true'
        environment name: 'key2', value: 'true'
    }
    anyOf {
        environment name: 'key3', value: 'string1'
        environment name: 'key4', value: 'string2'
        environment name: 'key5', value: 'string3'
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi so this is the correct approach right. we need use allof. As i saw mine s working but not sure whether it is correct approach